# past -- a postpositive adjective?

Tags: adjectives, inversion, postpositive-adjectives

Usage example with [a context](http://www.businessinsider.com/why-putin-will-lose-2015-1):

> Putin, like Hitler, lives in a mental time-warp that was outmoded already in 1914 — see his strangely 19th century views on diplomacy — and would be laughably obsolete now, were it not so dangerous. Moscow’s imperial experiments **past** all failed, thanks to the limited appeal of the Kremlin’s political program to millions of non-Russians, and this one will too, eventually.

Is the word *past* used here as a postpositive adjective? So, that basically means *Moscow's imperial experiments that happened in the past all failed*?

Comment: Precisely. It is indeed a postpositive adjective.

Comment: I think u r right. It's a postpositive adjective.

Comment: What a disgusting text you're reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **past** is an adjective following the noun. It's unconventional word order, but this can indeed be done in English.

The inverted word order gives the phrase a grand, majestic feeling. Here, though, the feeling is somewhat ironic, since the point is that Moscow's grand experiments with [empire](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/48274/6700) failed. And yes, that really is what the sentence means, although anyone with even a passing acquaintance with [Russian history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Empire) knows it's absurdly false.*

The phrase **in times past** is actually common enough that everyone has heard it, so placing **past** after a noun, especially if you're referring to far-off history, doesn't seem like much of a stretch to fluent speakers. [This Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22times+past%22) brings up many books that contain the phrase. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202100?redirectedFrom=times+past#eid210183583) quotes it as far back as Shakespeare, and the phrase appears to be even older.

---

*** Maybe it just means Putin's attempts to start an empire, or attempts made after the fall of the Soviet Union. But putting **past** after **imperial experiments** suggests that one is talking about a long stretch of history, probably centuries, not just the last couple decades.

I see that the article also mentions Putin's "paeans to Muscovy's **heroes** and **greatness past**". This is another bit of grandiloquent prose, and clearly suggests a timespan of centuries.